# VScode is displaying (deleted) in tab bar when opening file from winSCP

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, winscp

I have a problem opening my file from winSCP using Vscode editor. It display deleted even though the file is still existing. I notice that when there is deleted in filename my pc is creating temp folder when I save it and the deleted file will save there and not in the server.

I try to open the file using double click and it display delete but when I try to open it using right click then click open there is no deleted in filename. I also try to delete the temp folder and open again the file the deleted is gone. There is no issue when there is no deleted in filename it save directly in server and not creating temp folder. It's weird I don't know what happen. Please someone could explain me why is this happening.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: See also [WinSCP and Notepad++: File does not exist anymore?](https://superuser.com/q/989538/213663)

Answer (score 2):

Go to the Editor Preference Dialog for VS-Code in winSCP and uncheck the line "External editor opens each file in separate window (process)"